# Swift: How to get everything after a certain set of characters

Tags: swift, swift2

Given the following string:

```
var snippet = "1111 West Main Street Beverly Hills, CA 90210 Phone: 123.456.7891"
```

How can I extract everything that comes after "Phone:"

So in this case I want

```
phone = 123.456.7891
```

I've tried this:

```
    if let range = snippet.rangeOfString("Phone:") {

        let phone = snippet.substringToIndex(range.startIndex)
        print(phone) // prints 1111 West Main Street Beverly Hills, CA 90210
    }
```

But this prints everything BEFORE, I need everything AFTER.

Comment: let phone = snippet.substringFromIndex(range.endIndex)

Answer (score 91, accepted):

In Swift 4, use `upperBound` and subscript operators and open range:

```
let snippet = "1111 West Main Street Beverly Hills, CA 90210 Phone: 123.456.7891"

if let range = snippet.range(of: "Phone: ") {
    let phone = snippet[range.upperBound...]
    print(phone) // prints "123.456.7891"
}
```

Or consider trimming the whitespace:

```
if let range = snippet.range(of: "Phone:") {
    let phone = snippet[range.upperBound...].trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
    print(phone) // prints "123.456.7891"
}
```

---

By the way, if you're trying to grab both at the same time, a regular expression can do that. E.g., in iOS 16 and later:

```swift
let snippet = "1111 West Main Street Beverly Hills, CA 90210 Phone: 123.456.7891"
if let match = snippet.firstMatch(of: /^(.*?)\s*Phone:\s*(.*)$/.ignoresCase()) {
    let address = match.output.1
    let phone = match.output.2
}
```

Or in earlier iOS versions, we might use `NSRegularExpression`:

```swift
let snippet = "1111 West Main Street Beverly Hills, CA 90210 Phone: 123.456.7891"
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: #"^(.*?)\s*Phone:\s*(.*)$"#, options: .caseInsensitive)
if let match = regex.firstMatch(in: snippet, range: NSRange(snippet.startIndex..., in: snippet)) {
    let address = snippet[Range(match.range(at: 1), in: snippet)!]
    let phone = snippet[Range(match.range(at: 2), in: snippet)!]
}
```

---

For prior versions of Swift, see [previous revision of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/34075093/3).

Comment: first code snippet returns us `String.SubSequence`. To get `String`, we should use second code snippet which trims the white space and returns `String`, right?

Comment: Sorry for not responding to the comment earlier: Yep, if you are passing this result to a method or property that is expecting a `String`, then you can create a string from a substring (e.g. `let string = String(address)`), which involves copying the contents of a substring into another `String`. Alternatively, sometimes you can define your method to accept both strings and substrings by using `StringProtocol` rather than `String`. The question comes down to whether you need a separate `String` (and the overhead that entails) or whether you want to enjoy the efficiency of substrings.

Answer (score 21):

for a very basic way and assuming you can guarantee the format of the string you could use `.components(separatedBy: "Phone: ")` so  anything before will be at index 0 and after index 1

```
var snippet = "1111 West Main Street Beverly Hills, CA 90210 Phone: 123.456.7891"
let phoneNumber = snippet.components(separatedBy: "Phone: ")[1]
print(phoneNumber)
//prints everything that appears after "Phone: " in your snippet string
//"123.456.7891"
```

Comment: This code not conforms to the requirements in the question. It will fail with several "Phone:" occurrences in the input.

Comment: The Question did not state multiple occurrences of "Phone:". So your issue may not actually exist. To quote my own answer though "assuming you can guarantee the format of the string"

Answer (score 4):

Check it this

```
let delimiter = ", "
let newstr = "Hello, playground"
let token = newstr.components(separatedBy: delimiter)
let first = token[0]
let last = token[1]
print("\(first) \(last)")
```

Comment: This solution can easily cause an 'Index out of range' error if the newstr is empty for example.

Comment: @marika.daboja we should not use my code when newstr is empty. Make sure use guard condition if newstr is empty

Answer (score -3):

Just use `func substringFromIndex` but increase the index by the length of `"Phone:"`