# Extract a name from a sentence

Tags: ios, swift

I need to get persons name from a sentence.

Example : `My Name is David Bonds and i live in new york.` and I want to extract name `David Bonds`.

`My Name is` is definitely will be in every sentence. but after the name it can contains rest of the sentence or may be nothing. from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34075093/2475420) I was able to get to the point of `My Name is`. but it will print out rest of all the sentence. i want to make sure it will grab only `next two words` only.

```
 if let range = conversation.range(of: "My Name is") {
    let name = conversation.substring(from: range.upperBound).trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    print(name)
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have rest of the text you can separate it by " ". Then first and secont elements are first and last name

```
let array = text.components(separatedBy: " ")

//first name
print(array[0])

//last name
print(array[1])
```

Answer (score 8):

It's almost time for **Swift 4, iOS 11** in which using `NSLinguisticTagger` is a bit easier.

So, for future reference, you can use NSLinguisticTagger to extract a name from a sentence. This doesn't depend on the name following a named token, or a two word name.

This is from an **Xcode 9 Playground**

```
import UIKit

let sentence = "My Name is David Bonds and I live in new york."

// Create the tagger's options and language scheme
let options: NSLinguisticTagger.Options = [.omitWhitespace, .omitPunctuation, .joinNames]
let schemes = NSLinguisticTagger.availableTagSchemes(forLanguage: "en")

// Create a tagger
let tagger = NSLinguisticTagger(tagSchemes: schemes, options: Int(options.rawValue))
tagger.string = sentence
let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: sentence.count)

// Enumerate the found tags. In this case print a name if it is found.
tagger.enumerateTags(in: range, unit: .word, scheme: .nameType, options: options) { (tag, tokenRange, _) in
    guard let tag = tag, tag == .personalName else { return }
    let name = (sentence as NSString).substring(with: tokenRange)
    print(name) // -> Prints "David Bonds" to the console.
}
```

**Edited September 2023**

It's been a while since I wrote this answer and things have changed. `NSLinguisticTagger` was deprecated in iOS 14 in favour of the new `NaturalLanguage` framework

A modern version of doing this is now:

```swift
import UIKit
import NaturalLanguage

let text = "My Name is David Bonds and I live in new york."

// Create an NSTagger instance based on NameTypes
let tagger = NLTagger(tagSchemes: [.nameType])
tagger.string = text

// Configure the tagger
let options: NLTagger.Options = [.joinNames]
let tags: [NLTag] = [.personalName]

tagger.enumerateTags(in: text.startIndex..<text.endIndex, unit: .word, scheme: .nameType, options: options) { tag, tokenRange in
    // Get the most likely tag, and print it if it's a named entity.
    if let tag = tag,
       tags.contains(tag) {
        print("\(text[tokenRange])")
    }
   return true
}
```

Comment: Damnit! You got there just before me. I was about to post a similar answer. Worth noting that this is possible in iOS 5 and above but slightly harder to use :D

Comment: Do you know how many times that's happened to me? The sun shines on everyone sometimes :)

Comment: I copied the exact code above, but it prints nothing, even the official code from https://developer.apple.com/documentation/naturallanguage/identifying_people_places_and_organizations doesn't work for me, do you know why?

Comment: @SasanSoroush I've updated the answer. NSLinguisticTagger is deprecated and you should be using the NaturalLanguage Framework instead.

Answer (score 2):

You could implement it as follows:

```
let myString = "My Name is David Bonds and i live in new york."

// all words after "My Name is"
let words = String(myString.characters.dropFirst(11)).components(separatedBy: " ")

let name = words[0] + " " + words[1]

print(name) // David Bonds
```

As a remark, `dropFirst(11)` should works fine if you are *pretty sure* that "My Name is " should be before the name, since its number of character is 11.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code

```
let sen = "My Name is David Bonds and i live in new york."

let arrSen = sen.components(separatedBy: "My Name is ")
print(arrSen)

let sen0 = arrSen[1]

let arrsen0 = sen0.components(separatedBy: " ")
print("\(arrsen0[0]) \(arrsen0[1])")
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: in my sentence cannot gurantee there will always be `and` keyword.

Comment: @ImBatman you really should be using the lexical tagger like in Abizern's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the prefix string "My Name is David " and then separate it by " ".

```
var sentence = "My Name is David Bonds and"
let prefix = "My Name is "

sentence.removeSubrange(sentence.range(of: prefix)!)
let array = sentence.components(separatedBy: " ")
print("Name: ", array[0],array[1])  // Name:  David Bonds
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want the data:

```
let string = "My Name is David Bonds and i live in new york."

let names = string.components(separatedBy: " ")[3...4]
let name  = names.joined(separator: " ")
```